# SQL: Basic Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a more detailed description ready, but I thought I'd try the simple one first.

```
X    Y
7    F
7    F
7    E
7    F
8    F
8    F
```

I want to do something else based on figuring out if for a value (x) of X there is a value of F in Y for all of the x's in the corresponding table.  This means 7 doesn't cut it, and 8 does.  How do I code this using a subquery?  Do I use ALL?  I wrote a query but it returns true whenever there is one match instead of all.

Comment: A simple way is it to use `GROUP BY` and a condition in `HAVING` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following query

```
select distinct X from temp
except
select X from temp where Y!='F' -- x,y columns, temp -> table

--Query select all distinct X which has all Y as F
```

Following is alternative query for the same

```
select distinct X from temp where not exists (select X from temp where Y='E')
```

Answer (score 1):

`Select * from mytable 
 where X not in ( Select X from mytable 
                              Where Y <> 'F'
                            )`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without a subquery like this in most major RDBMSes

```
SELECT x
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY x
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN Y = 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

or

```
SELECT x
  FROM table1
 GROUP BY x
HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN Y <> 'F' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Output:

```
| X |
|---|
| 8 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcb2ea/4)** demo (MySQL)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0f7f5/3)** demo (SQL Server)
Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2cca4/2)** demo (Oracle)

Comment: @user963070 Did it help after all?